# What does '' that '' refer to?

Tags: phrase-meaning

In this sentence, what does *that* refer to, *them* or *element*?

> We will use the symbol 'R' for the element in them **that** is anaphorically related to an antecedent.

Comment: It doesn't refer to anything, It's simply a meaningless subordinator introducing the relative clause "that is anaphorically related to an antecedent". Have you thoroughly read the material that contained that quote?

Comment: There is a certain irony about asking a question about the use anaphora in a text that describes in detail the use of anaphora.

Answer (score 3):

The relative pronoun "that" refers to "*the element in them*".

We can replace it and get a meaningful clause that fits the context:

> **the element in them** is anaphorically related to an antecedent.

Answer (score 2):

> *We will use the symbol 'R' for the element in them* [*that is*
> *anaphorically related to an antecedent*].

"That" doesn't refer to anything. It's not a relative pronoun but simply a meaningless subordinator functioning as a marker introducing the bracketed relative clause.

The relativised element, 'R', is represented by the gap notation '___', which in this case is in subject position, and it's this gap, not "that",   which refers to the antecedent, the nominal "element in them".

> *We will use the symbol 'R' for the element in them* [*that ___ is*
> *anaphorically related to an antecedent*].

In other words it's not "that" which is anaphoric, but the gap '___'.